# what are the components to formulate a unique identifier like GUID

Tags: vba, uniqueidentifier

I have recently heard about GUID which is a global unique identifier. However, i would like to formulate my own unique identifier with components such as random numbers, timestamp, ip adress and userID. I would like to have my end result to be in the format of 19 digits (long variable). What are the other components that i can add? I am currently using Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
set obj = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")  
msgbox obj.GUID
```

If you want your own then create it.